# How to use normal text along with mathjax in same line?

Tags: discussion, mathjax, formatting

I was trying to display both normal text and mathjax generated output continuously in the same line. I've tried configuring inline technique using \$ but failed. I also tried \text{...} which does not seem to work. Also used \begin \end tags. Then found somewhere \intertext suggestion. Nothing worked.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can't do both at once

Comment: e.g $n \; \text{odd}$ or something else?

Comment: I think this is really more suitable for a MathJax forum or the TeX.SE. In any case I think by default one has to use `\(` and `\)`. If you want the behavior most people want you have to tweak the configuration.

Comment: $$\frac{\text{\text}}{\text{what you want?}}$$

Comment: Could you attempt to show us?  It'd be insightful

Answer (score 1):

We know that
$a=\sqrt{b}$.

The above was entered as

We know that
\$a=\sqrt{b}\$.

Comment: \$ is disabled by default. How to enable it?

Comment: @AbdullahAdilMahmud   I checked your \$ and it is hexadecimal 24 which is correct, so it should work. Do you have a $ sign on your keyboard or are you entering it some other way?

Comment: I do. @JohnWaylandBales

Comment: @AbdullahAdilMahmud That is like saying "yes" to a chocolate or vanilla question.

Comment: @Abdullah   Could you copy and paste the second line from martycohen beginning with 'We know . . ." into a comment and see what results?

Comment: Did similar things. Actually the problem now is configuring single dollar. @John

Comment: For single dollar do $\backslash$\$ or perhaps I misunderstood your meaning. You mean by single-dollar inline math?

Comment: @AbdullahAdilMahmud   The math is not rendered until you hit 'enter'.

Comment: Solved. Thanks all!